# fabricjs - how to stop font fallback?

Tags: fabricjs

Is there a way to stop fabricjs's Text object to fallback to other font family when the glyph is not existing?

Or, is it able to change the fallback font family?

I expect that it shows rectangle box(notdef) when the glyph is not existing inside the chosen font family. This serves a purpose to let user know the chosen font family is not supporting the typed character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The fontFamily option is allowed to have multiple font like CSS. So, the fallback font(default Time News Roman) can be overridden like below code.

```
new fabric.Text("some text here", {
    fontFamily: font_type+", NotDef", //font_type is some dynamic font
});
```

Comment: Does this allow you to specify an emoji font so If someone inputs an emoji it will fall back to that?